RecurrenceActivityId for IsRecurrence2
We're working on a migration needing to determine the original parent record for Events using the Recurrence2 system.  The original recurrence system had a RecurrenceActivityId to tell you the parent record.
It seems like Recurrence2 doesn't have anything to indicate the parent record, or even if it IS a parent record.
Am I missing something?  Or is this just yet another half-baked Salesforce feature.

As per Salesforce:

Lightning Experience event series have no series ID, so it’s not possible to locate other occurrences in the series.

As for a work around: if you create a custom field on Activity and set it when creating the initial Event, all series events will have that field. You could automate this with a trigger that sets this custom field to the id of the event if it is a recurring event and the custom field is null. So while it won't be a lookup relationship, it will be queryable.

makes sense, but doesn't really help in our cases as we are migrating existing data...
I did at least figure out we can determine which event is the OG by matching the ActivityDateTime to the Recurrence2PatternStartDate.
What a horrible implementation (especially given it was the second attempt at it)
